# bind onPress to View has no effect in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I wanna bind a onPress event to a view ,got no effect.But work fine in its child View(it's a Text View);Here's my code:

```
  <View style={styles.loginByPhoneBtnContianer} onPress={this.makeLogin} >
       <Text style={styles.loginByPhoneBtnTitle}>
        Login
       </Text>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `onPress` event in `View` component you should use a `TouchableHighlight` or a `TouchableOpacity` component instead of it.

Comment: Happy to help you. I will be appreciated if you upvote it.

Comment: that' s sure :3

Answer (score 2):

It works fine after I changed my View to TouchableHighlight:)

Comment: You can also use TouchableWithoutFeedback if you just want to add onPress func to it.